# why function in react app will not render

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

The code runs without errors on the console.Even after i write the if block no error is in the console,but the react app wont display any JSX ,just blank page

my code works when you remove the if(} block

```
import { useState } from "react";
const Zoom = () => {
  const [btnable, setbtnable] = useState(true);
  const [stoke, setStoke] = useState("");
    if (stoke === "") {
      setbtnable(btnable);
    } else {
      setbtnable(false);
    }

  return (
    <div className="container">
      <span>Zoom</span>
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>2</td>
          <td>3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>4</td>
          <td>5</td>
          <td>6</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>7</td>
          <td>8</td>
          <td>9</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>10</td>
          <td>11</td>
          <td>12</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
      <br />
      <input
        type="number"
        placeholder="Stoke"
        onChange={(e) => {
          setStoke(e.target.value);
        }}
      />
      <button disabled={btnable}>Zoom</button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Zoom;
```

Comment: this part here: `setbtnable(btnable)`, what exactly do you want to do there? not an expert in react, but it seems like it's unnecessary because it will set itself with the old value. Depends on what you want, maybe remove that line or change it to `setbtnable(true)`.

Comment: The setbtnable(btnable)  is meant to hold its initial value until the if block changes it. But now the if block is causing issues

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is an infinite render.

When you update component state, you cause that component to rerender.

Every time the component rerenders, the if else block is being run again. Which is calling set state again. Which is causing the component to rerender, and calling the if else again, and setting state again, rendering again and.... you get the point. It's an infinite loop.

When you're executing any upfront logic that causes state to change, you should wrap it in a useEffect with a supplied dependency array to manage when the code gets executed, and prevent unintended state changes from dooming you to an infinite loop of rerendering.

Your code is confusing me and you didn't explain what you want the behavior to be. But my guess is you want this, or at least something like it:

```
const [btnable, setBtnable] = useState(true);
const [stoke, setStoke] = useState("");

useEffect(() => {
   if (stoke === "") {
      setBtnable(true);
   } else {
      setBtnable(false);
   }
}, [stoke]);
```

Read up on component rendering, state changes, useState and useEffect hooks. Seems like you're missing some key insights which is causing your confusion here. Best of luck.

Comment: yea you're right, i was missing the useeffect hook.Oh gosh i encountered another problem,the button wasn't enabled as i hoped it would,because that was the function of the if block

Comment: When do you want the button to be enabled/disabled? With the code I provided, it's disabled initially and when stoke is empty. Which is what it seemed like you were trying to do. If it's the opposite, you can swap the if else and initialize btnable to false.